# React Native App does not start on iOS after some days

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

I'm using React-Native 0.31. I successfully deployed my app to my iPhone with "Release Build" settings. Everything is working fine but after 2-3 days the app is not staring anymore. Even a restart of the iPhone does not help. Only a reinstallation of the app via xCode solves the problem.

Does anyone has a hint why this this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read the device logs while trying to open the app? Plug the device into your computer and in the Devices window of Xcode, watch the console for logs while trying to open the app. You may see something meaningful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked the log on the iphone but without any successful hint. 
It turend out that it has something to do with the provisioning profile. After some days this profile expires which causes that the app is not starting anymore. A solution is to you "Apple test flight" for beta testing. This extends the period of time.