# Any way to make React Native ios app for personal use?

Tags: ios, react-native

I am making an ios app using React Native for the first time as a self learning exercise. I don't intend to launch it to the Apple App Store but it'd be nice to be able to use the app myself on my phone.

I've successfully deployed my app to my iPhone with "Release Build" settings, but after 3 days the app stops launching (with message "yourApp is no longer available"). I understand this is something to do with the provisioning profile expiring after x amount of days and a reinstall of the app from xcode is needed (from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959573/react-native-app-does-not-start-on-ios-after-some-days))

Does anyone know any way to get around this? Or must I purchase a developer licence and go through deployment to the app store just to get my app working on my phone permanently? Thanks in advance!

Comment: At the slim chance you don't use any native code (the whole app is in Javascript and has no Obj-C/Swift dependencies) you can use [Expo](https://expo.io/) to load it on the device. 

Apple offers an Enterprise distribution method, which bypasses the App Store, however this is limited to companies of 500+ employees.

I don't know whether you can load an ad-hoc distributed app (the thing you are trying to do) permanently.